# Firestore Database not functioning online

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a Cloud Firestore Database and have it in Test Mode which means the read and write rules are pretty open for the next 3 weeks.

However when I try to add collections or documents from the web interface they do not show up on the database. I was able to add collections and documents from my android app but even those when I try to view I get "Error loading Documents".

I have tried Firefox and Chrome to see if it was a browser issue and I have disabled my Antivirus (avast) as well to see if that was the issue but no success.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Use the log output to log what errors are occured. It's not easy to specify a problem with out proper details there are n chances for that to happen. Post your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to debug or answer this, you require backend assistance: I suggest reporting the problem to Firebase support. but most likely by the time you get a response, the server will fix itself.

https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact